# Sync single accounts calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

I have added 2 accounts in Outlook. For Ex. consider them as 'A' and 'B'. My problem is that the calendar events from the account `B` are automatically synchronized to calendar events in `A`, So every time I will have to delete the calendar events of `B` in `A`.

How can I stop synchronizing `B`'s calendar in `A` ? I would like to view them by their corresponding accounts ?

- Account A is Office 365 account
- Account B is IMAP account(of Gmail).
- MS Outlook version: 2013.

Comment: The problem is that your IMAP Gmail account is using the same Outlook "data file" as the Office365 account - so when it downloads events from your Gmail, it's syncing them to the same calendar as Office365.  I think the solution is to remove and re-add the Gmail account using a different data file.  If I can figure out the exact steps, I'll post them as an answer.

Comment: No both have a different data file, but still the calendars are syncing.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the auto-sync option on exchange admin center will help.

Here is the reference [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771204.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Sorry but it is not an administrator account.