# Stop outlook from adding external meetings into personal (365) calendar

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, calendar, gmail-imap

I use outlook with 2 accounts, my personal 365 email, and my work email (Gmail, IMAP).
When I receive a calendar invite on my work account, it gets added to my personal 365 calendar and syncs to all my devices.

How do I stop this? I want work events to be added to a separate calendar, or not synced at all.

Related: [Sync single accounts calendar](https://superuser.com/questions/1013106/sync-single-accounts-calendar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File > Options > Mail > In the tracking section, uncheck '**Automatically process meeting requests and responses to meeting requests and polls**'

Comment: This actually works! Just note it seems to affect all IMAP accounts, but luckily not Microsoft accounts, so it accidentally has the correct result for me . Just thought I'd leave this note here in case anyone is using multiple IMAP accounts though. Thanks!

Comment: Such good news!!